# WPF OneWay binding ObservableCollection to Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am new to WPF a trying to do simple data binding with Treeview. I have ObservableCollection treeViewItems with one item and I want to display it with TreeView but I am struggling with the binding in XAML.
Here is my code:
C#

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<FileItem> treeViewItems = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>
        {
            new FileItem
            {
                Name = "sdfsdfs",
            }
        };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
    public class FileItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML

```
        <TreeView x:Name="FilesTreeview" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=treeViewItems}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileItem}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Comment: Check the output window when you have trouble with bindings, it will tell you about binding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`treeViewItems` is a field, you cannot bind to fields, you need a public property, so e.g.

```
public ObservableCollection<FileItem> treeViewItems { get; } = ...
```

*(The naming convention would also prefer the name `TreeViewItems`)*

Comment: You would also have to set the Window's DataContext to itself in its constructor: `DataContext = this;`

Comment: @Clemens: Possibly, if that is not in the XAML.